# When you pass a callback to a useState setter function, where does that callback receive its own arguments from?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I'm really curious about this block of code:

```
const countDown = () => {
    setMillis((time) => {
      if (time === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
        onEnd();
        return time;
      }
      const timeLeft = time - 1000;
      return timeLeft;
    });
  };
```

From this larger file here: https://github.com/mobinni/FocusTime/blob/countdown/src/components/Countdown.js

Specifically, how does setMillis' callback function ever receive a variable for time? I can't see anywhere where a variable would ever be passed to countDown that could go to setMillis's callback function? This is generally just a very confusing block of code for me. Where would the value for time ever come from?

Answer (score 1):

The function `setMillis` is the setter function of a state. A setter function for a state receives the current state as an argument. This is by design. The framework does this as documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). The first argument of the setter function of a state is an `updater` function which receives `state` as an argument.

> `state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied.

You have the freedom to call this variable however you like.

In summary: the `useState` hook is an internal functionality provided by the React framework. It consists of two things: a `state` object and a `setter` function which can be used to update the state. The state handling is performed by React in the background. Hence, the reason we can access `time` in your example is because the framework passes it to our updater function.

Comment: Thank you! React ensures in the background that the setter function receives the state object -- great explanation.

Comment: Exactly. You are welcome! I'm glad it helped.